# Implementing Data Quality checks in PySpark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to automate few specific data-quality checks on an input PySpark `Dataframe` based on some specified columns before loading the DF to a PostgreSQL table. The Dataframe's column-names that require the checks and their corresponding data-types are specified in a Python `dict` (also provided as input).

Now, For each record in the Dataframe the following checks needs to be performed:

- Null checks on the columns mentioned in the dict
- Duplicate check on the columns mentioned in the dict
- Data Type check of the columns and their corresponding data types
  mentioned in the dict

So far I have been able to implement the "Null-check" requirement logic (given below) to provide a feel about what I am trying to achieve.

I was hoping if someone could please help with the logic to implement the remaining data-checks mentioned above (especially for the "data-type" check requirement).

E.g: input dict =>

```
{"emp_id": "integer", 
 "emp_name": "varchar(10)", 
 "emp_salary": "float", 
 "upd_ts": "timestamp(YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ)"}
```

Basically all the fields in the input DF is `varchar(255)`. Now the program has to perform all the checks mentioned above based on the information provided in this `dict` in the format `{colname: datatype}`.

For e.g. For **NULL**-check of the specified fields, I can do the following:

```
query = ""

for col_nm in input_dict.keys():
    query = query + col_nm + " IS NULL OR "
query = query + " 1=0"
null_count = input_df.filter(query).count()

if null_count > 0:
    print("Null check failed...")
else:
    print("Null check successful...")
```

Any help on the remaining checks is appreciated. Happy to provide more info. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked onto existing packages like pydeequ or Great Expectations? They work and you don't need to reinvent things

Comment: @Alex, thanks much for your input. I will certainly look into it. Unfortunately, we are not allowed to install any new packages etc (without going thru the pain of getting scores of approvals !)

Comment: another one that might be useful: https://github.com/mikulskibartosz/check-engine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own and your if your use case is not super complex, you can use something like below as template (and if you can/want to use DataFrame API instead of Spark SQL):

```
    data = [("Alice", 25, None), ("nonCapital", 22, "Engineer"), ("Charlie", 30, "Doctor"), ("NoAge", None, "Doctor")]
    columns = ["Name", "Age", "Occupation"]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

    def starts_with_capital(name):
        return name is not None and name[0].isupper()

    starts_with_capital_udf = udf(starts_with_capital, BooleanType())

    def apply_filters(df, filters):
        filtered = df
        for f in filters:
            if f['check'] == 'notnull':
                filtered = filtered.filter(col(f['col']).isNotNull())
            elif f['check'] == 'startswithcapital':
                filtered = filtered.filter(starts_with_capital_udf(col(f['col'])))
        return filtered, df.subtract(filtered)

    filter_list = [{'col': 'Age', 'check': 'notnull', 'rule': 1}, {'col': 'Name', 'check': 'startswithcapital', 'rule': 2}]

    good_values, bad_values = apply_filters(df, filter_list)

    # Show the result
    good_values.show()
    bad_values.show()
```

This code will give output like below:

```
+-------+---+----------+
|   Name|Age|Occupation|
+-------+---+----------+
|  Alice| 25|      null|
|Charlie| 30|    Doctor|
+-------+---+----------+

+----------+----+----------+
|      Name| Age|Occupation|
+----------+----+----------+
|nonCapital|  22|  Engineer|
|     NoAge|null|    Doctor|
+----------+----+----------+
```